# Dynamic navigation from database

Tags: php, mysql, navigation

I have 2 tables in my database. One for product categories and one for sub categories.

The sub category table has a field holding their parent category IDs

Now im trying to create navigation using this information but am struggling to fetch only the categories out of the database that have a sub category.

**Table "Categories":**

catID | catName | active | image

**Table "subCategories":**

catID | catName | parentCatID | active | image

so far i have tried this:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT DISTINCT parentCatID FROM *****');
while($row = $sql->fetch_row()) {
  $rows[]=$row;
}                   
$res = join(',',$rows);
$sql2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ***** WHERE categoryID IN '" . $res . "'");
while($results2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){
    echo $results2['categoryName'];
}
```

This doesnt work and I cant see a solution.
It's easy enough to just select all the categories. But I dont want the ones that dont have a sub category

Comment: Edit your question to include the schemas of the tables you're discussing, so that potential answerers will be able to see what we're dealing with.

Comment: OK edited question to show table fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an INNER JOIN

```
SELECT *
FROM Categories
    INNER JOIN subCategories ON subCategories.parentCatID = Categories.catID AND subCategories.active = 1
WHERE Categories.active = 1
GROUP BY Categories.catID
```

Edited to reflect your structure, you will need to update the "active = 1" based on how you have that set up

Comment: Am trying this solution now but will have to let you know how I get on in the morning :( thanks for your input none the less

Comment: Thank you I have tried this this morning and got it to work :) it does what I need so thanks again. I found this solution easier than Styphon's so I will accept this answer

Answer (score 2):

The following query should select all the primary categories that only have sub categories:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT count(*) FROM subCategories WHERE parentCatID = Categories.catID) as num FROM Categories WHERE num > 0
```

As you haven't given us table or column names I've made them. Replace with your actual table and column names.

**EDIT** Added in table / column names now a schema is available.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I used your SQL statement and added the following lines after it:   

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{echo $row['catID'];}   

But I get nothing :/

Comment: Try doing `var_dump($row);`, that should output everything in $row. The other thing is to open PHPMyAdmin and run the query there, see if it gives you any results, or an error.

Comment: var_dump produces nothing and running the query in phpMyAdmin also produces nothing. no errors but no results either

Comment: Not sure why that didn't work for you but I'm glad the other answer did work for you.